# Tab / LF / CR unicode character

Tags: ruby, unicode, iconv

I have a Unicode file (UTF-16 FFFE little-endian BOM) which contains rows of tab-separated fields.

Read [Splitting unicode (I think) using .split in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308112/splitting-unicode-i-think-using-split-in-ruby), I am going to use the Ruby split (file to lines, then line to fields).

BTW, what's the Unicode char for:

- LF
- CR
- Tab

Thanks!

Comment: Is that really your question, what are the codepoints for those three characters in Unicode?

Comment: I agree, is that really the question? This could have been answered with a quick check on the internets but for future reference: http://www.unicode.org/charts/#symbols and in particular http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_Unicode_block

Comment: I am asking both, the unicode char, and the unicode code in Ruby syntax. 

assume blob (blob = Record.first.file_attached) is storing the UTF-16 raw data. then: rows = blob.split("\u000D") 

rows.size return 1

if I do a u8rows = Iconv.conv("utf-8", "utf-16le", blob).split("\n")

u8rows.size is 232

my question is: what is the unicode CR/LF char for splitting a UTF-16 FFFE blob, in Ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
LF:  U+000A  
CR:  U+000D  
Tab: U+0009
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 4):

Unicode TAB is `u0009`. LF is `u000a` and CR is `u000d`

Same as ASCII actually.

Comment: Simply because the first 256 code points of Unicode are the same as in Latin-1. Which in turn uses ASCII for the first 128.