# What's discouraging you from writing ruby 1.9-specific code?

Tags: ruby, backwards-compatibility, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

So far, I've been merely using YARV (ruby 1.9) as merely a faster implementation of ruby than ruby 1.8, and ensured that all of my code is backwards-compatible with ruby 1.8.6. What circumstances, if any, are stopping you from writing 1.9-specific code?

One reason per answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, if we're talking about rails, then the problem there is the compatibility of gems/plugins with ruby 1.9. I'm sure everyone who wants to upgrade to 1.9 keeps an eye on <strike>isitruby19.com</strike>

Answer (score 3):

The first release candidate for Ruby 1.9.2 is due end of May and I believe many are waiting for 1.9.2 to hop on the 1.9 train.

Not really an answer to your question, but to start writing code uses 1.9.2 methods now, you can `require "backports"` and most features will be available to you, even in Ruby 1.8.6 (albeit not nearly as fast, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could [forget about Iconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445175/tab-lf-cr-unicode-character) when handling unicode data, like this:

```
Iconv.conv("utf-8", "utf-16le", blob).split("\n")
```

but so far I **could not find good examples**/tutorial of 1.9 unicode handling yet.

Comment: I found this enlightening: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/understanding_m17n

Comment: Here's an even better one: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/

Answer (score 0):

In many operating systems, it is easier to install ruby 1.8 than ruby 1.9.

- Some distributions of Linux have packages for 1.8 but not for 1.9.
- <s>OS X has ruby 1.8.7 pre-installed.</s> 1.8.7 runs the ruby 1.9 language.
- The one-click installer for Windows is ruby 1.8.

Comment: If you're writing a gem/library, you don't know what platform your users are using. (I wonder if we'll ever see isitruby18.com?)

Comment: If the "don't know what platform" answer was compelling, we'd all need to keep targeting Ruby 1.6 or earlier, and no new features in the language would _ever_ be used.

Comment: When did people switch from 1.6 to 1.8, and how did people handle things then? Or was it not really a problem because people weren't writing gems?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is discouraging me.  I've been using Ruby 1.9.1 for everything I do for close to a year now and had few problems.  My [major](http://github.com/SFEley/candy) [gems](http://github.com/SFEley/acts_as_icontact) *require* 1.9 for various reasons (easy UTF-8, fibers, etc.) and I've felt no qualms about it.  For some other [trivial](http://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-sessionography) gems I might make a token effort to keep them 1.8 compatible, which mostly just means not using the cleaner new hash syntax.

1.9 is the current Ruby.  I can see needing to keep the old Ruby around for legacy code that isn't worth updating, or having a preference for an alternative Ruby (JRuby, Rubinius, etc.) -- but it truly baffles me why so many people are still starting new projects in the slower, obsolete Ruby 1.8.x line.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Ruby so well to distinguish 1.8 from 1.9 ( well that's  my reason :P  )